# Any performance issues when removing Macbook battery?

Tags: macbook-pro

Does anyone know if removing the battery will have a major effect on the performance of the processor for the Macbook Pro 15" (Early 2011)? I ask because my laptop gets really hot - the heat in Australia doesn't seem to help, and I barely move my laptop around. Just wondering if this would reduce the heat produced.

Thanks :-)

Comment: I can't comment on the performance, but I believe removing the battery will result in it having a longer lifespan.

Comment: Why don't you replace the battery with new (If it's old and susceptible to heat problems) and get a cooling pad? The problem is, if you accidentally catch the power connector and it disconnects then the laptop will power off. Unlike a PC where the base unit is usually positioned where the cable is unlikely to be accidentally unplugged...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they run slower. From [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/apple-macbook-pro-battery-benchmarks,6643.html), December 2008:

> Gearlog was benchmarking to test third party RAM modules for use in the new MacBook Pros, but discovered that the notebook’s processing power significantly decreased after the battery was removed during the test.
>
> [...]
>
> Gearlog’s own results show a decrease of 36 percent in processor speeds without a battery attached on their unibody MacBook Pro. Our own tests show a decrease of 50 percent when rendering with one CPU, a decrease of 52 percent in multiprocessor rendering, while the GPU suffered a 40 percent decrease in performance.

Apple used to document this in [HT2332](https://web.archive.org/web/20130615084258/http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2332) (but [the official link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2332) is dead):

> **MacBook and MacBook Pro: Mac reduces processor speed when battery is removed while operating from an A/C adaptor**
>
> If the battery is removed from a MacBook or MacBook Pro, the computer will automatically reduce the processor speed. This prevents the computer from shutting down if it demands more power than the A/C adaptor alone can provide.
>
> **Additional Information**
>
> **Important**: It is strongly recommended that you do not use your MacBook or MacBook Pro while the battery is removed. Accidently bumping the A/C adaptor could disconnect power and shutdown the computer. Any information that was not saved on your computer would be lost.